# Problems with wires declared inside verilog generate blocks

Tags: declaration, verilog

Within a `generate` block, I have multiple `if` statements. When I declare a wire in the first if statement - I can't use it in other `if` statements

See the following stripped down example of my module:

```
module my_module 
#(parameter integer NUM_X_PORTS = 1,
  parameter integer NUM_Y_PORTS = 1)
 (
  // port declarations
 );

generate 

  if (NUM_X_PORTS > 0) begin
    wire [NUM_X_PORTS-1:0] x1;
    // logic filled in here
  end

  if (NUM_Y_PORTS > 0) begin
    wire [NUM_Y_PORTS-1:0] y1;
    // logic filled in here
  end

  if ((NUM_X_PORTS > 0) && (NUM_Y_PORTS > 0)) begin
    for (i=0; i<NUM_Y_PORTS; i=i+1) begin
      assign z[i] = y1[i] & |x1; // I can't use x1 and y1 here
    end

endgenerate
```

The error message from both VCS and nLint is that indentifiers x1 and y1 have not been declared.

But they have been declared within previous generated if statements - what is the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wires `x1` and `y1` are defined outside of scope of the assignment. One solution is to add and reference scope labels:

```
if (NUM_X_PORTS > 0) begin : scope_x1
  wire [NUM_X_PORTS-1:0] x1;
  // logic filled in here
end

if (NUM_Y_PORTS > 0) begin : scope_y1
  wire [NUM_Y_PORTS-1:0] y1;
  // logic filled in here
end

if ((NUM_X_PORTS > 0) && (NUM_Y_PORTS > 0)) begin : scope_z
  for (i=0; i<NUM_Y_PORTS; i=i+1) begin : scopes_z_i_ // loop has unique scope
    // x1 & y1 accessed by scope label found by its parent
    assign z[i] = scope_y1.y1[i] & |scope_x1.x1; 
  end
end
```

For the assignment to work, the declaration of `x1` and `y1` must exist withing the scope of `scope_2` or its parent.

```
if ((NUM_X_PORTS > 0) && (NUM_Y_PORTS > 0)) begin  : scope_z
  wire [NUM_X_PORTS-1:0] x1;
  wire [NUM_Y_PORTS-1:0] y1;
  // logic filled in here
  for (i=0; i<NUM_Y_PORTS; i=i+1) begin : scopes_z_i_ // loop has unique scope
    assign z[i] = y1[i] & |x1; // everything is withing scope_z
  end
end
```

In both this cases `x1` and `y1` are limited in scope. If you do not wish the wire to exist when its respected `NUM_*_PORTS > 0` is false, then you must follow the first example.

See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 27. *Generate constructs* for more on generate